# How do you automatically remove the preview window after autocompletion in Vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, preview

I'm using `omnifunc=pythoncomplete`. When autocompleting a word (e.g., `os.<something>`), I get the list of eligible class members and functions, as expected, as well as a scratch buffer preview window with documentation about the selected member or function. This is great, but after selecting the function I want, the preview window remains.

I can get rid of it with  `:pc`, but I'd like it just to automatically disappear after I've selected my function, a la Eclipse. I've played around with `completeopt` but to no avail.

Comment: good question - I stopped using omnicomplete because it left that stupid buffer open.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Put the following in your vimrc:

```
" If you prefer the Omni-Completion tip window to close when a selection is
" made, these lines close it on movement in insert mode or when leaving
" insert mode
autocmd CursorMovedI * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
```

Comment: This seems to break the command edit window for me (q: or q/). I added another check: && bufname("%") != "[Command Line]" to both lines

Comment: @Ben: Woah how did I not see your comment before posting [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11733388/79125). The answer I got from there was to change `pclose` to `silent! pclose`.

Comment: Thanks to both gotgenes and pydave. Your tricks work perfectly!

Answer (score 82):

Even though there is already an accepted answer I found this directly from the docs which will work for any plugin that is having this issue.

```
autocmd CompleteDone * pclose
```

Comment: `CompleteDone` was added in version 7.4. This method should be preferred over `CursorMovedI`/`InsertLeave` approach.

Comment: @PeterRincker I prefer the window not to close on completion (because I want to see the documentation as I'm typing in the arguments), so I will be using the `InsertLeave` line.

Answer (score 19):

If you have the supertab plugin installed, there is an option called `supertab-closepreviewonpopupclose`.

Put the following in your .vimrc:

```
let g:SuperTabClosePreviewOnPopupClose = 1
```

Comment: I upvote this answer because it's a hint that the YouCompleteMe plugin has a g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion option.

Comment: @AndyHayden Glad I can help! That's what I left the comment for!

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how to close it automatically, but you can type

> :pclose

to close the scratch preview manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw in the following mappings to have certain keys try to close the preview window.

```
inoremap <space> <C-O>:wincmd z<CR><space>
inoremap ( <C-O>:wincmd z<CR>(
inoremap ) <C-O>:wincmd z<CR>)
inoremap , <C-O>:wincmd z<CR>,
inoremap <CR> <C-O>:wincmd z<CR><CR>
inoremap <esc> <esc>:wincmd z<CR>
```

You could also use autocommands to close the preview window when you're finished in insert mode:

```
augroup GoAwayPreviewWindow
autocmd! InsertLeave * wincmd z
augroup end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but after days of looking for a "clean" solution I just found the CompleteDone autofunction that does the job:

```
au CompleteDone * pclose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type that in the `.vimrc`:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```

Comment: Cou you please care to explain more?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, this keeps the preview window from ever popping up, not being dismissed after completion.  Note that the OP did say they tried "completeopt" as well.